# C2535 with template-class in unordered_map (Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 CTP6)

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-map, visual-studio-2015

I'm getting a strange C2535-compiler error while trying to compile the following code:

```
template<int NUMBER>
class Container {
public:
    bool operator==(const Container& other) const { return true; }
};

namespace std {
    template <int NUMBER>
    class hash<Container<NUMBER>> {
    public:
        size_t operator()(const Container<NUMBER> & state) const {
            return 0;
        }
    };
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    auto* b = new std::unordered_map< Container<1>, int>(); //C2535
}
```

Note that if I use a my own template-based Hasher

```
template<int NUMBER>
class Hash {
public:
    size_t operator()(const Container<NUMBER> & state) const {
        return 0;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    auto* b = new std::unordered_map< Container<1>, int, Hash<1>>();
}
```

the code compiles just fine. And I remember that the code was being compiled without a hitch in Visual Studio 2013 Express.

Question: Is this a VS 2015 - bug or is this behaviour in some way standard-conforming?

Comment: std::hash is not a class. It's the struct. See live http://rextester.com/VHHQE6270

Comment: @user2451677: As far as I know, struct is just a class with the default access being public instead of private. Anyway, a template-based **struct** Hash was perfectly compiled!

Comment: @user2451677 Good point. I thought it was declared `class hash`.

Comment: @user2451677: Now I see your point :)

Comment: @Mischa, you are partially specialize template. So, it must be exactly "
the same" as primary template.  struct Hash works because it's new template (primary template), not specialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this is made ill-formed by a subtlety in §14.5.1/4:

> **In a** redeclaration, **partial specialization**, explicit specialization or
>   explicit instantiation of a class template, **the *class-key* shall agree
>   in kind with the original class template declaration** (7.1.6.3).

And, according to §20.9/2, `hash` is declared as

> **Header `<functional>` synopsis**
>
> ```
> // 20.9.12, hash function primary template:
> template <class T> struct hash;
> ```

Hence try

```
template <int NUMBER>
struct hash<Container<NUMBER>> { /*…*/ };
```

instead.